# Universally create Derived class from Base in python

Tags: python, class, architecture, derived-class, base-class

Found some questions on SO but still have no answer... There is a data class

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
```

There is a getter class which is supposed to read these data from different sources

```
class FileProxyGetter(ProxyGetter):
    def __init__(self, fname = "d:\\proxies.txt"):
        self.fileName = fname 

    def Get(self):
        proxies = []

        f = open(self.fileName)

        for l in f.xreadlines(): 
            proxies.append(Proxy.fromstring(l[:-1]))

        f.close()

        return proxies

    def Update(self):
        return []
```

I need to have a Proxy class with more options like

```
class SecureProxy(Proxy):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        super(SecureProxy, self).__init__(ip, port)
        self.transparent = None
```

Now I want to improve FileProxyGetter as follows:

```
class FileSecureProxyGetter(FileProxyGetter):
    def Get(self):
        proxies = super(FileProxyGetter, self).Get()
        secureProxies = []
        for proxy in proxies:
            # Create or Cast Proxy to SecureProxy.
            # The transparent should be initialized to None or any other value that I may need
            secureProxies.append(SecureProxy(proxy))

        return secureProxies
```

So **how do I cast or create an instance of derived class from base class** in Python universally. It would be better if no changes to the classes needed.

*Or can you suggest more pythonic way of developing such relationships and architecture*?

Comment: I dont get the point - you have `Proxy` and `FileProxyGetter`. Then you write `SecureProxy` and you want that `FileSecureProxyGetter` appear automatically - thats right?

Comment: @GillBates No, I created it manualy. I want to cast create SecureProxy out of Proxy calling only SecureProxy constructor

Comment: Not that it solves your problem, but your way of reading the lines of a file has two issues. Firstly, use a `with open(..) as f:` to open and automatically close the file, which works even in the presence of exceptions or an early return. Then, `for line in f:` is  the idiomatic way to iterate over the lines of a file. That said, to address your problem at hand, have you considered using a metaclass that registers all derived classes in a factory? Alternatively, you could pass the correct type to `ProxyGetter.Get()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use inheritance:

```
class FileProxyGetter(ProxyGetter):
    ...
    def MakeProxy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Proxy.fromstring(*args, **kwargs)
    def Get(self):
        ...
           proxies.append(self.MakeProxy(l[:-1]))
        ...
    ...
class FileSecureProxyGetter(FileProxyGetter):
    def MakeProxy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return SecureProxy.fromstring(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it's probably more useful in this case to use composition.

```
class FileProxyGetter(ProxyGetter):
    def __init__(self, proxyclass, fname = "d:\\proxies.txt"):
        self.proxyClass = proxyclass
        self.fileName = fname
    ...
    def Get(self):
        ...
            proxies.append(self.proxyclass.fromstring(l[:-1]))
        ...
    ...

# use this as such
FileProxyGetter(Proxy, "proxies.txt")
FileProxyGetter(SecureProxy, "secure_proxies.txt")
```

EDIT: A dirty trick in python to switch the type of an object:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print 'hello A'
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print 'hello B'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo()
hello A
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a.__class__ = B
>>> a.foo()
hello B
```

Another dirty trick for two objects of different types to share the same state:

```
>>> class B(object):
...     def rename(self, name):
...         self.name = name
... 
>>> class A(object):
...     def say(self):
...         print 'Hello', self.name
... 
>>> a, b = A(), B()
>>> a.__dict__ = b.__dict__
>>> b.rename('john')
>>> a.say()
Hello john
>>> a.rename('mary')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'rename'
>>> b.say()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'say'
```

However, these tricks, while possible in Python, I would not call them pythonic nor a good OO design.

Another possibility in Python 3.x and up, which had removed "unbound method" in place of using regular function:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def say(self):
...         print('Hello', self.name)
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def rename(self, name):
...         self.name = name + name
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> B.rename(a, 'josh')
>>> a.say()
Hello joshjosh
```

Comment: The first one is great but I don't like in this solution that Base classes Need to know that there are "kinds" of Proxy classes.
Actually I want to create a derrived from base when I have the base instance already

Comment: @Romeno: In python, variables are typeless, while objects are strongly typed. There's several dirty tricks to switch the class of an object, see the edit on my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies that python has no such built-in ability because even with those tricks the __init__ is not called and I should design the class with the thought in mind that it can be used that way.

Comment: @Romeno: you can call __init__ yourself if you want to. Alternatively, you can do the __dict__ swap inside `SecureProxy.__new__(proxy)` to emulate an "unsafe up-casting" behavior from other languages. Doing this isn't a good OO design, though Python does make it possible (doing the same in C/C++ will very likely get you silent memory corruptions; or a ClassCastException in Java). More importantly though, what are you really trying to do? There are perhaps better, more OO, and more pythonic way to do what you need to do.